# Parse Variable from MySQL-Result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a nested variable in my mysql column, now printing it out, I would like it to also being parsed within my script but am not sure how to do it, I even tried doing double `$$id` and it still didn't work.

Here's what I have:

Pulled from mysql, $message now has = `Your order $$id is not ready yet.`

```
$id="234";
echo $message;
```

prints:

```
Your order $$id is not ready yet.
```

really want it to show:

```
Your order 234 is not ready yet.
```

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @habibulhaq $message prints `Your order $$id is not ready yet.`

Comment: what he means is, how is message defined?

Comment: I hate to say `eval`

Comment: no need to eval, if there's a placeholder in `$message`, it just needs to be replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$message` is coming from a database, it should look like the below, in which case you can do the following.

```
  $message = 'Your order $$id is not ready yet';
  $id = "234";
  $message = str_replace('$$id', $id, $message);
  print $message;
```

For completeness - if your strings, and your replacement values were in an array - you could make it a little smoother:

```
  $strings = array(
    'Your order $$id is not ready yet',
    'Thank you $$name for your order',
  );

  $replacements = array(
    'id' => "234",
    'name' => "thevoipman",
  );

  foreach($strings as &$message)
  {
    foreach($replacements as $placeholder => $value)
    {
      $message = str_replace('$$' . $placeholder, $value, $message);
    }
  }
  print_r($strings);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there's a quicker way not using str_replace...... I did a mysql select to get $message

Comment: @thevoipman You need to replace it, it's one additional line - and i updated to match your message format

Comment: is there anyway I can parse whatever is from mysql select that has $xxx to use php's $xxx so I don't need to do 10's str_replace...

Comment: @voipman even if there were, it would still require an additional line. if you post a more detailed section of code showing the multiple strings that need replacing - then we can see if there's a better way

Comment: @thevoipman i've added an example of how you might be able to approach doing it in a less repetitive manner.

Comment: @thevoipman There's no real way around that. Even if you don't write it explicitly in PHP, it will happen behind the scenes.

Comment: @pala_i just have a bunch of $'s in my results and are defined inside the php script already... no arrays of any kind...

Comment: @thevoipman then you have to ask yourself what is more work - refactoring EVERYTHING to make this easier, or just adding 10x `str_replace`